# Elastic search return results if one field has value

Tags: elasticsearch

Hello i am trying to filter ES results, i have to return results if one field **at least** has value. So i have tried this, but not sure is it best approach or is it valid.

Query:

```
{
        bool: {
          must: [
            {
              term: { event_id: eventId }
            }
          ],
          should: [
            { exists: { field: 'overall_bracket_rank' }},
            { exists: { field: 'primary_bracket_rank' }},
            { exists: { field: 'gender_bracket_rank' }},
          ],
          minimum_should_match: 1,
        }
      }
```

So looking something like this

```
SELECT * from table WHERE event_id = :event_id AND (overall_bracket_rank IS NOT NULL OR primary_bracket_rank IS NOT NULL OR gender_bracket_rank IS NOT NULL)
```

Overall at least one not null value for specific event_id

Comment: It looks correct to me, except that you should use `bool/filter` instead of `bool/must` since you're doing an exact search and don't need scoring (more efficient to not compute score for no reason). Are you getting the documents you expect?

Comment: think so just to double check

Comment: wondering is minimum_should_match related to "should" key, it is little bit confusing.

Comment: Yes, `minimum_should_match: 1` means that at least one should match, which is what you want

Comment: great thank you sir!